# Why does my Fancybox plugin open locally stored videos in a new window?

Tags: jquery, video, fancybox, lightbox

I am trying to build a video carousel with a series of images that, when clicked, open a lightboxed video on the same screen. The images are all linked to the appropriate video:

```
    <div>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="arch" href="video/MotionTest_0001.mp4">
            <img src="img/videoStandIn.png" width="492" height="275" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

and I've checked the inspector, my browser is properly loading these scripts/stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js">    
</script>
```

And yes, I have included the oft-forgotten script at the top of the body in the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({});
    });
</script>
```

And yet, every time I click on a linked video it just opens up in a new window as if I had just stuck a regular link in the document. I have scoured the internet, and nothing I try seems to solve my problem. This is a really cool idea, and I would love any insight someone might have. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you get any error in firebug console ?  can u add jsfiddle

Comment: [The JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWXq9/3/) I _think_ this should be an accurate representation of what I have going on.

Comment: check my answer below.. i updated your fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify data-fancybox-type="iframe" for video carousel. here is your code updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWXq9/4/)  and one more working reference [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJfYF/25/) .. This should help you, let me know

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        padding     : 0,
        margin      : [20, 60, 20, 60] // Increase left/right margin
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually yeah, the iframe works way better. I think the problem was that I was directly referencing a locally stored video in a format that isn't compatible with the plugin (mp4). Thank you!